# Inject local Automake targets

Tags: unit-testing, makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

I am writing a library and planning to compile it with dependencies (such as GoogleTest). The build system looks something like this:

```
[PROJECT]
    |--- deps
    |--- src
    |--- tests
```

When running `make`, the source found in *tests* is excluded, and when running `make check`, the contents of *tests* is compiled and some unit tests run.

The initial idea for *deps* was for it to be compiled with unit tests when running a custom target such as `make deps`. How I immagine this to work would be something like:

```
% cat [PROJECT]/deps/Makefile.am
deps-local:
    SUBDIRS=gtest
    make check
```

Although this does not work it seems.

Another idea was to override `make check` in *deps* so that it at least does not run the unit tests (which take longer than my patience permits). I tried something like:

```
% cat [PROJECT]/deps/Makefile.am
SUBDIRS=gtest
check-local:
    make
```

Although this also was unsuccessful.

This have become a curiosity to me, and I would greatly appreciate some pointers. Cheers.